# Computing the year-on-year growth rate of a quarterly time series

Tags: r, time-series

I am discovering R and, although I see how powerful it can be, I am also a bit lost.
In that case, I have a quarterly times series, called Inflation.
My goal is to compute the yoy growth rate for each quarterly data point. 
So basically, as it starts in Q1 1981, I want to do (Inflation Q1 1982 - Inflation Q1 1981)/Inflation Q1 1981 for the 1st point, and so on and so forth...

When I do a diff(Inflation,lag=4) I get the first part, that is (Inflation Q1 1982 - Inflation Q1 1981).
But how do I tell R to divide that by Inflation Q1 1981 for the 1st point, then by Inflation Q2 1981...

Coming from other languages, my first approach would be a loop but I am sure R can do that more quickly and more efficiently.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you have it

```
> series <- ts(1:12, frequency = 4, start = c(1981, 1)) # example of quarterly serie
> series # this is how `series` looks like
     Qtr1 Qtr2 Qtr3 Qtr4
1981    1    2    3    4
1982    5    6    7    8
1983    9   10   11   12
> diff(series, lag=4)/ lag(series, k=-4) # the result you want
          Qtr1      Qtr2      Qtr3      Qtr4
1982 4.0000000 2.0000000 1.3333333 1.0000000
1983 0.8000000 0.6666667 0.5714286 0.5000000
```

As another alternative, you can use:

```
> (series/lag(series, k=-4))-1
```

Comment: Great thank you! It looks so simple retrospectively! So much more efficient than doing a loop!

Comment: you can accept the answer if this really answers your question

Comment: Yeah sure...how do I do that?

Comment: Click the checkmark under this post, on the left. [See this guidance](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). And when you have enough reputation points, you can also upvote it. ;)